# not able to protect adding duplicate data using sqlite database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using sqlite database to save and fetch data but each time but webservice runs it adds multiple duplicate data in the table. I also have upgrade method. What to do please help.

// code

```
      @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ORDER);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: Use unique key(I am not referring to primary key) so that duplicate datas are not stored again  then handle it in try-catch. It's your preference if you wanted to perform an update query in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add your array list whatever you have into linked has set and then recast into array list then your duplicate element would be removed and then you can insert your data into database now you will got the fresh list without duplicate values.
Another way also we have but firstly try this after I will suggest you another.
if my answer is helpful then appreciate me.

Comment: and you can add unique on each column so you can also remove duplicate.